# CakePHP 3.3: on tests, it asks for error templates

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've a plugin with only one controller with only one action:

```
class AssetsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Renders an asset
     * @param string $filename Asset filename
     * @param string $type Asset type (`css` or `js`)
     * @return Cake\Network\Response|null
     */
    public function asset($filename, $type)
    {
        $this->response->type($type);
        $this->response->file(ASSETS . DS . $filename);

        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

This only sends an asset file.

Now I'm writing a test for an asset file that does not exist.

```
public function testAssetNoExistingFile()
{
    $this->get('/assets/css/noexistingfile.css');

    $this->assertResponseFailure();
}
```

But it asks for error template:

```
1) Assets\Test\TestCase\Controller\AssetsControllerTest::testAssetNoExistingFile
Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException: Template file "Error/error500.ctp" is missing.
```

The plugin does not have template and there is no app with templates. So I would expect that it uses templates from CakePHP core, but this does not happen. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Error/error500.ctp` template in the core, that's something that the application has to supply.

When testing plugins, you should register a proper test application environment, and provide the necessary templates for it. If you look at how the CakePHP core and plugins do it, they create/register a dummy application in the `tests` folder where such template files can then be placed.

See also

- **[Setting up CakePHP 3 Plugin testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565066/setting-up-cakephp-3-plugin-testing/35611216)**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/3.3.3/tests**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/tree/3.3.3/tests**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/bake/tree/1.2.8/tests**

Comment: I have an app for tests, but I did not believe that it should also integrate templates. So I have to add error templates and a default layout. Ok, thanks @ndm

Comment: Sorry: error templates and an error layout! Ok, it works now.