# How to set the dependence to a plugin inside another plugin in Cakephp 4?

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

I'm creating a plugin `FileManager` in cakephp4. (This plugin is in **app/plugins/FileManager**)

This plugin has an `UploaderHelper` that contains a method to generate an input file + the files that are associated to the field.

In this method I'm using the plugin `CakephpGlide` (https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-glide) to display thumbnails of the images that are associated to the field.

How can I set up properly the dependence to the plugin `CakephpGlide` in my plugin `FileManager` ?

Note that I also use `CakephpGlide` in my Application (e.g outside of `FileManager`).

For now, I've only added in **app/plugins/FileManager/composer.json** a line in require  :

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "admad/cakephp-glide": "^5.0", // This one
        "cakephp/cakephp": "^4.3"
    },
```

Is there something else to do ?

I mean should I have to only write in the doc of my `FileManager` the way to configure `CakephpGlide` (in routes and AppView of the user's App) ?

And where will be stored the plugin `admad/cakephp-glide` in this way ? in app/vendors or in app/plugins/FileManager/vendors ?

I'm a bit confused..

Answer (score 0):

If you do not distribute your plugin / make it a standalone plugin, then all the files in your plugin's root are irrelevant, you could delete them and everything would still run fine.

A first party plugin in the `/plugins/` folder is part of your application, and therefore your application level `composer.json` should know about and require the dependencies for it.

Comment: OK. But what if I wanted to distribute my plugin later (we never know !), How should I process ?

Comment: @Oliv Then you'll restructure things so that your plugin doesn't live inside an application, but instead a test application lives inside your plugin, and thus your plugin will hold the project's root `composer.json` where all dependencies are defined. See how other standalone plugins are structured, for example **https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/** (also **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565066/setting-up-cakephp-3-plugin-testing/35611216#35611216**, a bit dated, but the concept still applies).